# Software or Python library to visualize 3D $N$-Body simulation

Tags: orbital-motion, computational-physics, simulations, celestial-mechanics, software

I have a bunch of .csv file that represent the position of 5000 points in space  i a have 500 of these file , each file represent  the new position of these point after a time interval. I would like to be able to visualize these point and to animate them to see there movement.   I would like the software to be able to scale for visualizing ways more then 5000 point each time  i would like to  have final result that can look like these:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fit1uX1HIlc&ab_channel=Jesse
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsCqkKZtRfU&ab_channel=Natt

(maybe be able to play with color like apply a color map to change color in fonction of density of point in a certain volume)

it can be a software or python libary i am also ready do a little bit of java or c++ to make it work ,
i want it to be able to plot data relatively easy and be able to handle a lot points

Comment: Check out glowscript.org or the vpython package for python.

Comment: sadly Vpython cant handle that much point

Answer (score 2):

C++/OpenGL would be a great way to visualize all of those points. Perhaps put some of your data files up on GitHub, and I will take a peek. Are you at all familiar with OpenGL?

That video link that you posted is for Vulkan, a competitor of OpenGL. Either way, you're looking at some graphics programming. I can help you with OpenGL code, and it will definitely be able to handle 5000 points at a time. There are a few control libraries for OpenGL. I prefer GLUT/GLUI or SDL/Dear Imgui, although you can always stick with Qt.

You can visualize the positions as points, or small spheres, white on a black background. Then run it through a bloom filter -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_(shader_effect)

Now, visualization aside, you can also forego 499 of those files, and start with just your initial conditions and simulate the evolution of the points' velocity and acceleration over time. With OpenGL this is relatively simple. You could use a compute shader, which is something that I am also familiar with.

This is called GPGPU -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units

There is only one problem with OpenGL on Mac -- Apple doesn't support OpenGL 4.3, which is the version where compute shaders were standardized. That said, you can still use vertex/fragment shaders to do GPGPU, but it's a little more convoluted. Pretty much every other hardware manufacturer supports OpenGL 4.3+. Apple's got a screw loose in the head, or at least they used to.

Here's a sample compute shader code, to calculate the quaternion Julia set -- https://github.com/sjhalayka/qjs_compute_shader

Let me know.

P.S. Sorry, I wrote this as an answer because I don't have enough reputation points to leave a comment.

Comment: sorry for the late answer here is the code that generate the data and visualize it [link](https://github.com/uhapppy/N-Body-v2) i cant share the data on the github because of the size of it but the data is pretty much a cvs file where all the line represent the position of one Body in 3d space for exemple if i run a simulation with 1000 iteration and 500 Body i will have a cvs file with 500000 line and each line will look like this 0.,0.,0. (this mean that this body is a the position x=0 ,y=0 z=0) now i can have  up to 30000 Body  but i will implement the barnes-hut algorithm